# Extend university wifi network

Tags: router, wireless-networking, captive-portal, repeater

i live in a university campus and i can get wifi signal on the outside of my window but not in the house.

The solution i use at the moment is a usb wifi dongle outside connected to my laptop but the lack of an internal antenna make the connection quite unreliable at times.
So i was trying to find another solution to improve the reception of my network.
One idea is to setup a router on the outside (in a place with stronger signal) and redirect the connection inside the house with an ethernet cable but the problem is that our Uni Wifi is managed by a capitve portal (BlueSocket with DNS redirection to login page) and the authentication has to happen on the mac address that connect to the net (so the client appliance in this case).

If I use a router with Mac-Clone capability i will be able to be redirected trough the captive portal on my laptop computer and login from there or i need to setup my router to fill in the login page by itself?

There are other hardware/software solutions i can use to get what i want?

Comment: Why don't you talk to the IT dept of your University to see what the options are.  Maybe they can put a WAP INSIDE your building if it's University property. However, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: Also, https://www.google.com/search?q=wireless+repeater